# Offline mapping tile creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mktileoverlay

In one of my iOS application I want to show an **offline indoor map with navigation**. I searched it in google and then I found solutions like routeme, mapbox etc .But the thing is I have to do this without any external libraries for that I did a sample project using `mktileoverlay` and it is working fine with that sample map. My problem is  how I will make tiles for my indoor map with the proper structure and how to do navigation with that map. Thanks in advance.